# Dynamically add property to the application context for one integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I have got a set of integration test configured that way, that they use one Application Context, but for one of them i need to change/add a property to the context.

I have used `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"property=value"})`
but in result it simply started new context.

So how can i dynamically add property to the application context for one integration test with existing context?

Comment: You cannot. You will need either to refresh the context, which will destroy its usability for next tests using this, or just live with the fact that i creates a new context (which is what it should do in the first place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a different properties file and reference like this

`@TestPropertySource(value = {"classpath:cache-test/application.properties"}`)

Comment: Yep, yours variant works as well as mine, but problem was in another thing. 
Both of the approaches are starting new context, while i want to some kinda inject new property in existing context just for one test and that's all. 

I kinda expect this:
`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
    ctx.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
    ctx.refresh();`

but in annonation style manner